# iframe content from external source not loading in local HTML file on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iframe, wkwebview

I created a local HTML file in my iOS app written in swift. The HTML file is loaded into a WKWebView as follows:

```swift
let url = Bundle(identifier: myIdentifier).url(forResource: "localHtmlFile", withExtension: "html")
let htmlFormatString = try String(contentsOf: url)
loadHTMLString(string: htmlFormatString, baseURL: nil)
```

The HTML page contains an iframe which I expect to load an external page:

```html
<div>Test</div>
<iframe src="https://www.somepage.com"></iframe>
```

The local HTML file is loaded successfully, as I can see the `Test` text in the div. The iframe is also created, but empty. If I debug with Safari Developer Tools, there is just an empty html page, but nothing loaded. Also, a network request to the url is not performed at all.

But if I insert an external JavaScript file with `<script src="https://url-to-some-js">`, the JS code will be loaded successfully, so there are no network issues. Also, if I load the url directly with `webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))`, it's working fine. Only within an iframe, it's not working.

How can I make iframes to external resources working in iOS WKWebView? Is this blocked by iOS at all or do I have to configure something else?

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Comment: have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

Based on some googling, it looks like you need to use the delegate method for the webView to allow external sites.  Specifically, implement `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)` with the following recommended implementation:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    guard let requestURL = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString else { return }

    if requestURL.contains("somepage.com") {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
    else {
        // You don't need to cancel here, but you can implement your own logic here
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing this on desktop browsers, where you have a local HTML file and a remote iFrame causes some security issues, so I expect you're hitting the same problem here.

Can you move your local content to a remote server? It doesn't have to be the same as your iframe content, although that will make your life easier.

If you have a lot of local data, then you could send a POST request for the parent page containing a JSON object of your local data.